# How to setup Google's v8 javascript standalone engine for remote debugging?

Tags: remote-debugging, v8, embedded-v8

How do I setup/build/run a Google's V8 Engine so that I can call a sample javascript file and see it interpreted step by step all the way down to C++ code?

Comment: +1 for asking my question. :-)

Comment: While I'd love an answer to this question myself, I would like to share that I've found a reference to JSON related debugging here: https://code.google.com/p/v8-wiki/wiki/DebuggerProtocol; I know it's possible to connect a debugger to a port in the V8 engine, so I'm guessing this is the protocol used.  BTW: It does mention in-process based debugging using a function based API.  Searching the wiki doesn't produce anything however. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: this is how it used to be.

V8 [wiki page](http://code.google.com/p/v8/wiki/AddDebuggerSupport) provides sample "lineprocessor.cc" program that runs custom JavaScript and tells how to enable debugging for these scripts.

Comment: No, it does not.  For example, the wiki mentions things such as setting up a debug message handler, and several other things, while the example does not appear to utilize any of the mchanosms mentioned in the wiki, leaving a reader to have to blindly guess how to actually hook things together.